# Обход графа в ширину

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы

Столкнулся с проблемой при решении задачи:
https://leetcode.com/problems/find-if-path-exists-in-graph/

> There is a bi-directional graph with n vertices, where each vertex is
> labeled from 0 to n - 1 (inclusive). The edges in the graph are
> represented as a 2D integer array edges, where each edges[i] = [ui,
> vi] denotes a bi-directional edge between vertex ui and vertex vi.
> Every vertex pair is connected by at most one edge, and no vertex has
> an edge to itself.
>
> You want to determine if there is a valid path that exists from vertex
> source to vertex destination.
>
> Given edges and the integers n, source, and destination, return true
> if there is a valid path from source to destination, or false
> otherwise.

на всякий случай транслейт:

> Имеется двунаправленный граф с n вершинами, где каждая вершина
> пронумерована от 0 до n - 1 (включительно). Ребра в графе представлены
> ребрами двумерного целочисленного массива, где каждое ребро [i] = [ui,
> vi] обозначает двунаправленное ребро между вершинами ui и вершинами
> vi. Каждая пара вершин соединена не более чем одним ребром, и ни одна
> вершина не имеет ребра сама с собой.
>
> Вы хотите определить, существует ли допустимый путь от источника
> вершины к месту назначения вершины.
>
> Учитывая ребра и целые числа n, источник и место назначения,
> возвращайте true, если существует допустимый путь от источника к месту
> назначения, или false в противном случае.

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Input: n = 3, edges = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]], source = 0, destination = 2
Output: true
Explanation: There are two paths from vertex 0 to vertex 2:

- 0 → 1 → 2
- 0 → 2

Написал код, который прошел 19/26 проверок. На 20 ой проверке в исходные данные я получил 2000 узлов, и решение не приняло по причине: **Time Limit Exceeded**

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно улучшить код, чтобы вписаться в лимиты. Спасибо. Собственно сам код:

```
public class Find_if_Path_Exists_in_Graph_1971 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=50;
        int edges[][]={{18,46},{8,48},{13,30},{28,29},{2,16},{7,36},{12,19},{31,16},{11,46},{6,46},{19,27},{4,24},{10,37},{14,37},{39,31},{10,22},{23,2},{47,11},{40,7},{21,17},{9,3},{34,10},{48,1},{21,35},{43,48},{27,5},{36,11},{43,36},{31,48},{25,33},{46,19},{31,30},{16,45},{30,10},{35,47},{35,13},{37,48},{49,3},{7,26},{2,30},{0,27},{25,9},{28,27},{39,18},{32,6},{14,43},{9,27},{27,4},{6,0},{21,43}};
        int source =48;
        int destination =2;
        System.out.println(validPath(n,edges,source,destination));

    }
    public static boolean validPath(int n, int[][] edges, int source, int destination){
        boolean result =false;
        if(source==destination)return true;
        //Создаем матрицу смежности:

        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

        for(int i=0;i< edges.length;i++)
        {
            matrix[edges[i][0]][edges[i][1]]=1;
            matrix[edges[i][1]][edges[i][0]]=1;
        }

        //print(matrix);
        //создаем очередь и для обхода в ширину и лист для хранения уже проверенных значений.
        Queue<Integer>queue=new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> checked = new ArrayList<>();
        queue.add(source);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()){
            int num = queue.remove();
            if(num==destination)return true;
            else checked.add(num);
            for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)
                if((matrix[num][i]==1)&(!checked.contains(i))) {
          //          System.out.println(i);
                    queue.add(i);
                }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void print(int [][] a) {
        for(int i=0;i< a.length;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

выход (с матрицей смежности)

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
true
```

Comment: насколько я понимаю, проверку `matrix[num][i]==1` делать бессмысленно. у вас же вся матрица в `1`.

Comment: @n1tr0xs та вроде нет. Раскомментировал print матрицы и добавил в вопрос. 1 только там где действительно есть ребра.

Comment: Но я обратил внимание на этот момент if((matrix[num][i]==1)&&(!checked.contains(i))) { добавил еще один символ & и проскочил этот пункт. и еще пару, но на 22/26 проверке, где 30000 узлов, уперся в лимит по памяти. (

Comment: Вам ненужна матрица смежности. Вам нужно уметь быстро перебрать соседей заданного узла. С матрицей смежности это задача O(n). Можно иметь массив списков соседей (ака "Список смежности").

Comment: Как быстро перебрать соседей? Я так понимаю рекурсия отпадает, так как при 30000 узлах, у меня стэк переполнится? То есть мне в цикле while для каждого узла нужно пробегаться по массиву edge, и добавлять их в очередь?

Comment: @had0uken  https://habr.com/ru/post/65367/  см "Списки смежности"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать множества для хранения соседей узла и [поиск в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) как алгоритм решения.

```
class Solution {
    private boolean path_exists;
    
    public boolean validPath(int n, int[][] edges, int source, int dest) {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[n];
        HashSet<Integer>[] graph = new HashSet[n];
        int i, j;

        // заполняем список соседей для каждого узла
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ // для каждого узла создаем HashSet ...
            graph[i] = new HashSet<Integer>();  
        }
        
        for(int[] edge : edges){ // ... и записываем соседей
            graph[edge[0]].add(edge[1]);
            graph[edge[1]].add(edge[0]);
        }
        
        if(graph[source].contains(dest)){  // если связь прямая - сразу выходим и возвращаем true
             return true;
        }
        
        path_exists = false;
        dfs(graph, visited, source, dest);
        return path_exists;
    }
    
    private void dfs(HashSet<Integer>[] graph, boolean[] visited, int source, int dest){
        if(!visited[source] && !path_exists){ // если не посещали вершину и не нашли путь
            if(source == dest){
                path_exists = true;
                return;
            }
            
            visited[source] = true; // отмечаем вершину посещенной
            for(Integer neighbor : graph[source]){ // для каждого соседа текущей вершины рекурсивно проверям путь
                dfs(graph, visited, neighbor, dest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Правда пока не понял как стек не переполнился от кучи вызванных рекурсий при большом графе. Я этого изначально боялся, поэтому при решении сразу отказался от использования рекурсии. Зря..

Comment: Два замечания по поводу боязни рекурсии: вы анализировали какой глубины стек допускает JVM на вашем железе? Это может быть полезно чтобы понимать когда нужно начинать бояться глубины рекурсии. Второе: любой рекурсивный алгоритм переписывается в итеративный. Для поиска в глубину это не сложно.

Comment: Для справки: на моём компьютере 20000 рекурсивных вызовов работает. С флагом -Xss32M отрабатывает миллион рекурсивных вызовов. Не о чем беспокоится в вашей задаче.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, попрактикуюсь, понабиваю руку